# Is it possible to export all user and usergroup from liferay to openldap?

Tags: liferay, openldap

Here is my portal-ext.properties :

```
ldap.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
ldap.server.name=ldapadmin
ldap.auth.enabled=true

ldap.import.enabled=false
ldap.export.enabled=true

ldap.import.on.startup=false
ldap.export.on.startup=true

ldap.export.method.0=group
ldap.export.method.0=user

ldap.password.policy.enabled=true
ldap.base.provider.url.0=ldap://localhost:389
ldap.base.dn.0=dc=test,dc=com
ldap.security.principal.0=cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
ldap.security.credentials.0=secret

ldap.auth.search.filter.0=(mail=@email_address@)
ldap.import.user.search.filter.0=(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)

ldap.user.mappings.0=userId=uid\nscreenName=cn\nemailAddress=mail\npassword=userPassword\nfirstName=givenName\nlastName=sn

ldap.import.group.search.filter.0=(objectClass=posixGroup)
ldap.group.mappings.0=groupName=cn\ndescription=description\nuser=memberUid
ldap.users.dn.0=ou=people,dc=test,dc=com
ldap.groups.dn.0=ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com

ldap.user.default.object.classes.0=inetOrgPerson, top
ldap.group.default.object.classes.0=posixGroup, top, groupOfUniqueNames,organizationalUnit
```

I want to export both users and userGroup from liferay to openldap whether they are associated or not with any userGroup or user.

Comment: What issues do you face with these settings?

Comment: I am not able to export UserGroups from liferay to openldap with these settings

Comment: Are all the users export working fine,I mean is the issue with User groups only?

Comment: yes, all users export working fine. but userGroup are not exporting.